# Best practice setup for maintaining gems in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, repository, bundler, production

What is the recommended setup for a Rails application running in the production environment with regards to gem management? Bundler handles dependency resolution, installing, updating, etc. well, but still relies on the gem repository being up and running at any given time and any required gem not being pulled (removed) from the repository.

Is there any way to achieve more redundancy (a local mirror of the gem repository, maybe?) with production gem management, so everything can continue to function normally if RubyGems has downtime or a required gem is removed?

Comment: This issue is one of the reasons Bundler was started in the first place. To quote Yehuda Katz: "Above all else, the bundler should provide a reproducible installation of Ruby applications. New gem releases or down remote servers should not be able to impact the successful installation of an application." So `bundle package` will do what you want as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the command "bundle package": Package the .gem files required by your application into the vendor/cache directory.